# mkdirs creates the folder in the desktop instead of inside the project folder

Tags: java

These two lines are supposed to create a folder in the project's folder but instead it is doing it on the desktop, I have to say it is a Dynamic Web Project with servlets, fetch api on the javascript side and all that, it is a Login for a school project:

```java
File folder = new File("media");
folder.mkdir();
```

It creates the folder on the desktop and it is not supposed to, since I am not passing the desktop path, and then I put the same two lines on a new java project, like the only code are these two lines and it works fine, that is, it creates the folder in the project folder, so why isn't it working on the Login project? any suggestion would be nice

Answer (score 3):

The `media` folder is going to get created in whatever location is specified by the "current working directory" (CWD).  What this location is defined as when your program starts is a matter of just how your program is launched.

You can print out what it is with this code:

```
String userDirectory = System.getProperty("user.dir");
```

(note that this is different than the user's home directory.). If you run this line of code just before the code you show above, then according to what you say, `userDirectory` will be set to the absolute path to the current user's Desktop directory.

Whenever you specify a relative path, which includes a value like you're using here that has no path component at all, the full system path is always constructed relative to the CWD.  To be safe, you're better off always specifying absolute paths instead of specifying relative paths and relying on the value of the CWD.

You can make Java Standard Library calls to get various well known path locations on your system to build absolute paths from.  For example, `System.getProperty("user.home")` will get you the current user's home directory.  You can also pass absolute root paths into your program at runtime, allowing you to specify where your data files are dynamically.

If you want to rely on the CWD's value, then make sure you understand what it is being set to based on how your program is launched.  For example, in IntelliJ, and I expect other IDEs, you can specify what you want the CWD to be when you launch your program via the Run/Debug parameters you set.

Comment: For further reading I can also recommend the [official documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/io/File.html).

Comment: Sadly I cannot use a property file for the exact same reason(I have to use absolute path otherwise it doesnt work), I must rely on the CWD since I have to upload this project on heroku, so I will get error if I use absolute paths. I'm not sure what you mean by "how your program is launched", I'm launching it by a index.html, otherwise it will not be launched correctly(meaning I will get errors), another thing is I have no main method, I'm not sure if that has something to do with. Flaxel, i cannot see the Java Api since long ago, it says "not available for thechnical issues"

Answer (score 0):

well, in the end I kind of figured out what was going on, I created a new class with a main method and printed these two lines, ran the proyect as a java application and it did work, so since I was launching this project by the index.html it was no using the project folder's path, but I have to "Run on server" this project or it just doesnt work, now what I did was I placed the java shortcut, which was in Desktop, into the project's folder and executed it from there, and it worked... I just find this funny, I'm not sure about this solution, I know there must be another solution for this, like really? do I have to carry a shortcut in the project's folder?...